# After slicing list , append is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Number 5 not getting added to list after slicing operation.Not sure why?

Tried remove slicing then got the desired output.

```
oldlist = [0,1,2,3]
newlist = oldlist
print (newlist)
oldlist.append(4)
print (newlist)
newlist = oldlist[:]
print (newlist)
oldlist.append(5)
print (newlist)
```

Expected output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5]
```

The output i got was

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: You append to `oldlist`, but prints `newlist`.

Comment: Yes @Austin i realized my mistake .Got the desired output.Thank You

Answer (score 1):

`newlist = oldlist[:]`

Unlike the straight assignment, this creates a copy of the list. Changes to `oldlist` will not apply to `newlist` after this point.